# The connection between a random variable's moments and its tails

Tags: distributions, moments

Suppose I know all the moments of some random variable XX. **When is knowledge of the moments sufficient to give one an understanding of the tail behavior?**

Is there a nice way to show that a random variable has exponential tails **just by looking at its moments?** In particular, I would be very curious if one could use *merely* the moments of the normal distribution to show that it has exponential tails. **Is this possible?**

Comment: Are you familiar with the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29)?

Comment: No, but looking at it now...

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure how this can be used to answer my question. One can find the moments with the characteristic function. But how does this relate to underestanding tail behavior, unless you can understand tail behavior with the characteristic function and you can somehow move from the moments to the characteristic function?

Comment: [But you can.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Moments)

Comment: @whuber This section is about the other direction: "characteristic functions can also be used to find moments of a random variable". Am I missing something?

Comment: The cf (and its logarithm, the cgf) are perhaps the best way to use moment-related information to analyze tail behavior of the distribution.

Comment: @whuber Forgive me if I am being obtuse, but your answers seem mysterious to me. I understand in principle how one can understand a distributions tails from its cf. But what if I only have the moments? Say they are finite. Under some conditions, do we have understanding of the tails?

Comment: Yes.  Most of the hits I get with searches that include the keywords [characteristic function](https://www.google.com/search?q=distribution+tail+characteristic+function&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) address your question directly.  That is why I mentioned it at the outset.

Comment: @whuber All the links I have seen show how you can move from the characteristic function to the moments, or from the characteristic function from the tails. I can't see one that goes from the moments to the characteristic function to the tails. Again, sorry if I am being obtuse.

Comment: Actually this: http://ipg.epfl.ch/~leveque/Advanced_Prob/lecture_notes8.pdf, is close to what I may want. Although I'm not familiar with these kinds of calculations

Answer (score 2):

Moments can be a guide to tail behavior only for those distributions for which the moments are defined. Nassim Taleb's free book *Silent Risk* (downloadable from his website) has one of the best expositions of heuristics that leverage the moments in defining the tails. But, and this is an important *but*, there are entire classes of *probabilistic* distributions which have infinite or undefined moments, e.g., the Cauchy or Lévy to name two.

The power exponent associated with the tail index offers one approach to classifying the behavior of a distribution that does not rely on the moment structure. While some contend that this tail exponent is readily estimable from a simple regression model, others are much less sanguine about this approach. E.g., see this paper by Clauset, Shalizi and Newman on tail exponents:  https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/agebreme/Networks/papers/clauset-powerLaw-siamRev05.pdf  To quote from the abstract:

> Power-law distributions occur in many situations of scientific
>   interest and have significant consequences for our understanding of
>   natural and man-made phenomena. Unfortunately, the detection and
>   characterization of power laws is complicated by the large
>   fluctuations that occur in the tail of the distribution—the part of
>   the distribution representing large but rare events— and by the
>   difficulty of identifying the range over which power-law behavior
>   holds. Commonly used methods for analyzing power-law data, such as
>   least-squares fitting, can produce substantially inaccurate estimates
>   of parameters for power-law distributions, and even in cases where
>   such methods return accurate answers they are still unsatisfactory
>   because they give no indication of whether the data obey a power law
>   at all. Here we present a principled statistical framework for
>   discerning and quantifying power-law behavior in empirical data. Our
>   approach combines maximum-likelihood fitting methods with
>   goodness-of-fit tests based on the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic and
>   likelihood ratios. We evaluate the effectiveness of the approach with
>   tests on synthetic data and give critical comparisons to previous
>   approaches. We also apply the proposed methods to twenty-four
>   real-world data sets from a range of different disciplines, each of
>   which has been conjectured to follow a power law distribution. In some
>   cases we find these conjectures to be consistent with the data while
>   in others the power law is ruled out.

In addition, this Wikipedia entry on the Tweedie distribution has an example of how the tail exponent can be used to assign distributions to one of several possible extreme value behaviors...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution

In the example you give using the normal distribution, its moments and, hence, its tails, are finite. In fact, since the normal possesses a finite moment structure, it's well known to be very "thin-" as opposed to "fat-" tailed. This is all very nicely explained in David Hand's excellent and recent book *The Improbability Principle*. Hand goes to great lengths to reinforce the notion that the normal is quite robust to violations, but this is definitely not the same thing as being "heavy-tailed."

The great example Hand provides is related to stock market returns following the August 2007 drawdowns and a Goldman-Sachs CFO's Senate testimony about the several day phenomena of "25-standard-deviation events," based on the normal distribution. As Hand notes, there aren't enough days since the beginning of time within which a 25-standard-deviation event could occur. In this case, a much better model of stock returns is the Cauchy distribution where these extreme moves have odds of occurrence of roughly 1 in 100 (see pages 147++).

Comment: So it can be proved that because the normal distribution has finite moments that it has exponential tails? Do you have an argument or a link to one?

Comment: The normal distribution is a member of the family of exponential distributions. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I KNOW that the normal distribution has exponential tails. I am asking if you can understand this from *just looking at the moments*.

Comment: Nope...not as far as I'm aware...but I will defer to others on this one...

Comment: The existence of an infinite moment implies at least one tail is "fatter" than exponential--and provides quantitative information about its decay rate.

Comment: But I am asking about the other direction. I have knowledge of all the moments. Suppose they are all finite. Can we say anything about the tails?

Comment: Yes, of course. For instance, it immediately implies the tails are not powers.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But perhaps we can't know that the tails are exponential. Seems like a subtle question.

Comment: @AlmostShirley  I don't want to seem impertinent but why are you so concerned with exponential tails? What is driving this...for want of a better word...obsession? For instance, consider this Wiki discussion of *natural exponential families* of distributions... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_exponential_family

Comment: @DJohnson Because I have a random variable that I hope has exponential tails, but for which I ONLY have information about the tails. I know that they are finite. And I know something about how they grow. I thought understanding how this would be possible with the normal distribution might give me some insight into the general case, so I could apply it to my not-well understood random variable. Make sense?

Comment: @AlmostShirley Maybe it makes sense. Do you understand that distributional assumptions about a random variate are rarely fixed and that multiple distributions can be made to fit the same information? What attributes or characteristics do you associate with "exponential tails" that make them so desirable?